# Puppet Master: TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2) - WEBrick 1.3.1

Tags: http, ruby, puppet

I rebooted Puppet Master several times but always this error

```
[root@puppet-master04 ~]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
[root@puppet-master04 ~]# service puppetmaster restart
Stopping puppetmaster:                                     [FAILED]
Starting puppetmaster:                                     [  OK  ]
[root@puppet-master04 ~]# cd /var/log/puppet
[root@puppet-master04 puppet]# ls -lrt
total 16
-rw-rw----. 1 puppet puppet 6605 Sep  2 10:25 masterhttp.log-20150906
-rw-rw----. 1 puppet puppet  187 Sep 24 10:49 masterhttp.log-20150925
-rw-rw----. 1 puppet puppet  748 Nov  2 10:19 masterhttp.log
[root@puppet-master04 puppet]# tail -20 masterhttp.log
[2015-11-02 10:16:05] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-11-02 10:16:05] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-11-02 10:16:05] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
[2015-11-02 10:17:08] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-11-02 10:17:08] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-11-02 10:17:08] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
[2015-11-02 10:17:13] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-11-02 10:17:13] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-11-02 10:17:13] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
[2015-11-02 10:19:59] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-11-02 10:19:59] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-11-02 10:19:59] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
```

which port is already in use?
We use RHEL6.

Comment: what is the output "netstat -tulpn | grep 8140"

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to start puppet master twice:

- first from httpd , where I presume you are using passenger to start the puppetmaster
- secondly to start the puppet master service directly

Since you don't know what you want :), I would ask the person who installed it to tell you which one is correct. I presume the httpd one.

Comment: i did this.. how can i restore my mess up?